# Tensorflow import error:could not open dinamic library

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

i am using pop-os (linux) and  the anaconda environment.

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0 
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

Issue:

```
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-08-12 17:07:17.858229: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-08-12 17:07:17.858298: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (pop-os): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2022-08-12 17:07:17.957536: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

[this is screenshot,while importing tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTgtU.png)

Comment: Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link and verify if you have followed all the steps properly to install TensorFlow in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists, Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks for help this issue is resolved now .